# Simple java swing crashes the OS

Tags: java, swing

I've encountered a strange problem, whenever I execute the following code, the OS freezes, or a blue screen of death appears.I've tried to compile it with JAVA 1.6 as well as 1.7

```
JFrame f = new JFrame();
f.setSize(100,100);
f.setVisible(true);
```

I'm running Windows 8

Comment: Update your JRE. This is the only thing I can think of, which could cause this. Not sure, since I am using Win 7.

Comment: Can you show us more code? Thats really interesty. No, Luigi thats not the case! I'm using Win 8 and my JRE is like 1-2 years old.

Comment: Maybe a missing `invokeLater(... setVisible(true))`. Otherwise do a virus scan.

Comment: not possible if isn't JRE 6/7 32/64 corrupted, I can't found significant diff on WinXP - 7(32/64) - 8(32/64)

Comment: Whatever the JRE you're using and the code you're executing, if Windows crashes, then it's a Windows bug or virus, and not a problem with the JRE or your code.

Comment: Another possible cause is the graphics driver. Swing uses DirectX and sometimes this doesn't play well together.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have had the same problem when the company upgraded from XP to 7. Solved by an upgrade to the JRE. Just move to the most recent release of whatever JRE major version you are using.